# Spectrogram of low-frequency data

Tags: plotting, fourier-analysis

I generate the following data

```
data = Table[Sin[2 π*100*t] + Sin[2 π*140*t], {t, 0, 10, 1/1023}];
```

and the spectrogram, as expected, shows two horizontal lines corresponding to the two frequencies:

```
Spectrogram[data, SampleRate -> 1023]
```

[image: Spectrogram 1]

Now, if I try to do the same with data at lower frequencies, such as:

```
data2 = Table[Sin[2 π*2*t] + Sin[2 π*6*t], {t, 0, 10, 1/1023}];
```

the spectrogram does not show the two frequencies, not even if I try changing the `PlotRange`.

What am I doing wrong? I have tried modifying the sampling rate, or changing the grouping in the `Spectrogram` function, but it does not seem to help...

Answer (score 2):

You have a range from `0` to `511.5`, so the frequencies at `2` & `6` are simply not visible. `PlotRange` itself doesn't help because you need to increase also the resolution:

```
Spectrogram[data2, 1024, SampleRate -> 1023, PlotRange -> {All, {0, 10}}, FrameTicks -> {{{2, 2}, {6, 6}}, Automatic}]
```

**v10.4:**

[image]

**v11.3:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! However I will accepted your answer, but I have a question: 1024 should be the number of partitions... How does it increase the resolution? Also, how could I get some sharp lines, rather than 1-pixel-wide lines? I can of course change the sampling rate of the data...

Comment: @zakk See the _Details and Options_ in the docs of [`Spectrogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Spectrogram.html) (and maybe also [`SpectrogramArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SpectrogramArray.html)).